# Convert FLV to MP4 or 3GP

Tags: php

Can I convert videos with PHP or do I have to use some library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use some libraries to achieve this.

The [Wordpress video solutions framework](http://wpvideo.wordpress.com/) already does video conversion; is written in PHP and uses [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org) and other tools to do the conversion. This may be a good starting point for you.